# Imagemagick non-conforming drawing primitive definition `matte' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/3284

Tags: imagemagick

I executed the following in console (cygwin x64) in Windows

```
 magick convert -verbose difference.png -fuzz 7% -draw 'matte 1,1 floodfill' test.png
difference.png PNG 216x107 216x107+0+0 8-bit Gray 11167B 0.000u 0:00.002
difference.png=>test.png PNG 216x107 216x107+0+0 8-bit Gray 8737B 0.078u 0:00.077
```

However, I got the following error:

```
convert: non-conforming drawing primitive definition `matte' @ error/draw.c/DrawImage/3284.
```

Please mention on how I can correct this error.

Comment: Try using `alpha` in place of `matte`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I see that it works. But do they do the same thing?

Comment: Several things have change between ImageMagick 7 and ImageMagick 6. The matte keyword is replaced with alpha keyword in the floodfill command. The process is still the same. Also in IM 7 you use magick, not magick convert. But you do need magick to preface identify, mogrify, montage, etc. Also -matte in IM 6 becomes -alpha set in IM 7 and +matte becomes -alpha off. There are other changes. See http://imagemagick.org/script/porting.php#cli

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The drawing primitive `matte` was replaced by `alpha` in ImageMagick 7. From [Porting to ImageMagick Version 7](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/porting.php) article.

> The DrawMatte() method is now called DrawAlpha().

As [Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell) pointed out in the comments, replacing `matte` with `alpha` should work as expected.

```
 magick convert -verbose difference.png -fuzz 7% -draw 'alpha 1,1 floodfill' test.png
```